# google maps select infowindow DOM element from angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to select the element by class 'gm-style-iw' to fix some styles in Infowindow. The selection is happening inside of the angularjs directive.

```
<div ui-view="full-map" id="full-map" class="mainMap col-xs-6"></div>
```

ui-view - loading a directive with IW content. map is initialized inside that directive.

on the directive's controller initialization i have to edit element with class 'gm-style-iw'.

```
   var iwElem = $document[0].getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")
```

does return the correct element.

***console.log(iwElem)*** result is:

```
[]
length: 1
0: div.gm-style-iw
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

However i'm stuck after it.
it as an `HTMLCollection`, which is the array of HTML elements, as i understand. => i must be able to get this `0` element by `iwElem[0]`, the strange thing is that `iwElem[0]` returns `undefined`.

Also tried with jquery selectors:

`$('.gm-style-iw')` => `length:0`

`$('div.gm-style-iw')` => `length:0`

Comment: ` i must be able to get this 0 element by iwElem[0]` yes & no, you'd want to try other numbers, or output that collection on the console and see what you can find in it. Wouldn't it be simpler to inject rules in to the gmaps info-window config object?

Comment: how many frames do you have your page? this looks like a frame issue. can you try the get elemet getters in different frames from dev tools once. also, are the frames same or cross origin?

Comment: i included an output from `$document[0].getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")` in the post. Wouldn't it be simpler to inject rules in to the gmaps info-window config - no, particularly the editions i want to make need to be done by removing some default classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your html is something like

```
<div ui-view="full-map" id="full-map" class="mainMap col-xs-6">
  ...some codes
  <div class="gm-style-iw"></div>
  ... other codes
</div>
```

And if your are using JQuery, how about trying the following selector?

```
$('.mainMap .gm-style-iw')
```

which means getting the child node of class `.gm-style-iw` under the parent node of class `.mainMap`

Comment: it's not exactly like that, but yes - i tried something similar and that doesn't help.
But why i can't get `$document[0].getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")[0]` ?

Comment: Sorry I did not notice angularjs, I will have a try at it.

Comment: If you are using the directive:controller, how about using element.getElementsByClassName rather than document.getElementsByClassName? like `controller: ['$scope', '$element',function MyTabsController($scope, $element) {}]`  See `Creating Directives that Communicate` in [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Would `element[0].querySelector('.gm-style-iw')` in directive function work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is partially solved.

```
  $timeout(function() {
      removeIwStandardStyles()
  },300);

  function removeIwStandardStyles () {
          var iwOuter = $(iwOuterTemp);
          while (iwOuterTemp.length < 1){
            iwOuterTemp = document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw");
          }

          var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

          iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});
          iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});
  }
```

`$document[0].getElementsByClassName("gm-style-iw")` was catching a corrent elements, but seems like they was not applied to DOM yet, or some other load issues.

However, the solution is not complete (see a `while`) - i suppose i can do that cause that element is definitely going to load. `$timeout` itself isn't helping completely - sometimes it does wait till complete IW load, sometimes not.